# How to create a resizable Abstract arrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, inheritance, arraylist

Suppose

```
class A{}
Class B extends A{}
Class C extends A{}
Class D extends A{}
Class E extends A{}
```

And I do the following

```
List<A> list1 = Arrays.asList(new B(), new C());
List<A> list2 = Arrays.asList(new D(), new E());
list1.addAll(0, list2);
```

It throws the following error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.addAll(AbstractList.java:260)
```

As far as I get it this exception means an abstract list cannot be resized. But I need a resizable Abstract Array List. Is there a way or any other idea.

Comment: "As far as I get it this exception means an abstract list cannot be resized." There is no _abstract list_, but what `Arrays.asList()` returns is a fixed-size list (backed by the array itself).

Comment: you can not modify the size of a result from Arrays.asList(new B(), new C())

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList` returns an `ArrayList` but this `ArrayList` is not the same as `java.util.ArrayList`, it is an internal class `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which extends `AbstractList`.

The `add` method is not overridden by this internal class, which means it calls `add` on the `AbstractList`. The `add` method on the `AbstractList` throws `UnSupportedOperationException`.

In order to use `addAll`, you need to use a collection that supports `addAll` for .e.g. `java.util.ArrayList`

Use `List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>( Arrays.asList( ... ) )` and then call `addAll` or `add`

Answer (score 0):

The `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is not resizable. So you could simply use an `ArrayList`:

```
List<A> list1 = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(new B(), new C()));
```

Or if you want to avoid the call to `Arrays.asList`:

```
List<A> list1 = new ArrayList<> ();
Collections.addAll(list1, new B(), new C());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` creates a `List` with a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.
As it uses under the hood an array and you cannot change the size of array once created, you cannot change the size of the `List` instance created by `Arrays.asList()` either.

If you want to use `Arrays.asList()` to ease the way to adding element in your `List` but you also want to modify it after its creation, you should wrap it in a new `ArrayList` instance that will copy all elements of it in the `ArrayList` :

```
List<A> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new B(), new C()));
List<A> list2 = Arrays.asList(new D(), new E());
list1.addAll(0, list2);
```

Comment: It's not unmodifiable, it has a fixed size.

Comment: @assylias You are right. Bad term.